# ¿Cómo asigno un valor de clave OneToOneField automáticamente en django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

Soy nuevo en django y me cuesta llevar a cabo una funcionalidad que en un principio pensé que era más básica y resulta que se complico bastante.
El problema consiste en que tengo en `models.py` un modelo llamado Usuario(funciona como si fuera el perfil del user) con clave llamada user de uno a uno que se conecta con la clase User.

```
class Usuario(models.Model):#TABLA DE LA BASE DE DATOS

    fecha_nacimiento =models.DateField(help_text='Fecha de nacimiento',null=True,blank=True)
    foto_perfil=models.ImageField(help_text='Elije una foto',null=True,blank=True)
    profesion=models.CharField(help_text='Profesión',max_length=30,null=True,blank=True)
    presentacion=models.TextField(help_text='Acerca de ti',max_length=200,null=True,blank=True)
    enlace_referencias=models.CharField(help_text='Link',max_length=50,null=True,blank=True)
    user= models.OneToOneField(
        User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True
    )

    def __str__(self):
      return self.user.username
def crear_usuario_perfil(sender,instance,created,**kwargs):
  if created:
    Usuario.objects.create(user=instance)

def guardar_usuario_perfil(sender,instance,created,**kwargs):
  instance.usuario.save()
```

#Éste es el formulario `forms.py`:

```
class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=140, required=True)
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=140, required=False)
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = (
            'username',
            'email',
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'password1',
            'password2',
        )

class Perfil(forms.ModelForm):   
   user=forms.CharField(max_length=140, required=True)
   class Meta:
        model = Usuario
        fields =('fecha_nacimiento','foto_perfil','profesion','presentacion','enlace_referencias',)
```

#Y ésta es la vista de `views.py` que renderiza:

```
class AddPerfil(CreateView):
    template_name='home/perfil.html'
    model= Usuario
    form_class=Perfil
    #form=AddPerfil(initial={'user':id_user})
    success_url='/'

    def get_initial(self):
        initial = super().get_initial()
        initial['user'] = self.kwargs ['slug']
        return initial
```

#Esta es la `urls.py`:

```
path('perfil/<slug>',views.AddPerfil.as_view(), name='perfil'),
```

Y éste es el `base.html`:

```
<a href="{% url 'home_app:categorias' %}">Categorias</a>
                        <a href="{% url 'home_app:como-funciona' %}">Como funciona</a>
                        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                            {% if user.Usuario.id is None %}
                                <a href="{% url 'home_app:perfil' user.username %}">Hola {{ user.username }}</a>
                                <a href="{% url 'home_app:sign_out' %}">Cerrar sesión</a>
                            {% else %}
                                <a href="{% url 'home_app:modify-user' %}">Hola {{ user.username }}</a>
                                <a href="{% url 'home_app:sign_out' %}">Cerrar sesión</a>
                            {% endif %}
                        {% else %}
                            
                            <a href="{% url 'home_app:sign_up' %}">Registrate</a>
                            <a href="{% url 'home_app:sign_in' %}">Iniciar sesión</a>
                        {% endif %}
```

Resumiendo, necesito que el user del usuario reconozca al user que se ha registrado(esta parte está funcionando bien, los usuarios si se registran correctamente) de forma automática. No se si asignárselo como lo estaba haciendo o no.

Como verán puedo pasarle correctamente un valor, en este caso el username, pero parece que no corresponde con el valor que necesito para que la relación se realice.

[image: Como verán puedo pasarle correctamente un valor, en este caso el username, pero parece que no corresponde con el valor que necesito para que la relacion se realice]

[image: ¿De qué manera entonces puedo asignarle un valores automáticamente cuando se trata de claves ya sean foraneas o uno a uno?¿Qué tendría que pasarle para que la relación sea completa?]

¿De qué manera entonces puedo asignarle un valores automáticamente cuando se trata de claves ya sean foraneas o uno a uno?¿Qué tendría que pasarle para que la relación sea completa?

Comment: Quieres que por defecto el usuario autenticado en ese momento se relacione automáticamente con el perfil?

Comment: Exactamente eso

Comment: La respuesta de @LeandroL es exactamente lo que quieres, recuerda aceptarla si resolvió tu problema o duda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba sobreescribiendo el metodo form_valid de la vista generica CreateView, de este modo:

```
class AddPerfil(CreateView):
    template_name='home/perfil.html'
    model = Usuario
    form_class = Perfil
    success_url='/'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.object.user = self.request.user
        return super(AddPerfil, self).form_valid(form)
```

y en el models.py

```
class Usuario(models.Model):
   .
   .
   .
   user= models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, editable=False)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda!

Comment: De nada, espero te haya servido la respuesta. Saludos

Comment: Como seria con APIView?